# Rendering geojson with DC.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I can get dc.js working with US map geojson, but not with different geojson. Here's my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/3dnkn75e/4/) and related snippet:

```
        usChart.width(990)
            .height(500)
            .dimension(states)
            .group(statesGroup)
            .colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"]))
            .colorDomain([0, 200])
            .colorCalculator(function (d) { return d ? usChart.colors()(d) : '#ccc'; })
            .overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features, "state", function (d) {
                return d.properties.name;
            })
        .valueAccessor(function(kv) {
            return kv.value;
        });
```

The code works with data associated with the var "statesJson", but not with "tractsJson". The "tractsJson" data renders in [geojson.io](http://geojson.io) (output [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb07d925b4dbb1d3cfce8267522d5cb2) as geojson). How to get code working with tractsJson data?

Are there any illustrative, complete dc.js code-examples that incorporate non-[US](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/vc/index.html) geojson maps? I've found a few related questions on Stackoverflow, but none that seem particularly helpful to me for the specific issue mentioned above and/or have complete, working code to use as reference.

Comment: Did you try setting the projection parameters to get the right zoom?